# Replacing an object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have created a jsfiddle to demostrate my problem

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/hin123/tcVhN/129/`
```

I have the add and delete button working in this example, but it seems I cannot find do the edit button. I am not sure what is wrong, help will be appreciated

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you are pushing an object in an array, how can you replace the object?

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash, sorry for the confusion, I should clear it up. I push an object in an array which then showed in the list view.Then in my list view, I redirect the list item to a edit form to display my object's detail and in this form there is an save button which can save my edited object's detail

Comment: clearing with more confusion dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must be using ng-repeat to render the list, and each list item must be having some edit button. On the click of the button you must be routing to the edit page.

The best thing will be to update the object at that index, instead of pushing a new object in the array.

You can update the factory's updateData method to something like this -

```
updateData: function (index, changedObj) {
    //merge the tempData object at position index and changedObject obj
    angular.extend(tempData[index], changedObject);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have got both list view and edit button working. I have this code pen  example http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/JsHjf . What I am struggling now is after I clicked the edit button, it will bring up a edit form which include each list's detail and a save button. I am struggling with the save button to save  the form details. I need some help with the code here to save the details. Thanks

Comment: Where are you caching your array? In a service?

Comment: Yes, it is in a sercice, i call my service as WebApi. To get all the array, I have a array in like this  var tempData =[] in the service and then to return it, I have a function getAll: function({ return tempData}) something like this

Comment: Can I do something like this in the savebutton?tempData.splice(index, 1);
tempData.splice(index, 0, newUpdateData);         and in my service i return something like getUpdateData: function(newUpdateData) { tempData = newUpdateData})

Comment: Hi Abhishek Prakash, I have created the plunker here, can you show me how to do it in this plunker? http://plnkr.co/edit/6xUhmd8SosOjGGZmOTrD?p=preview

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. I saw your plnkr and I believe these are the code snippet that is really troubling you. `WebApi.updateData($scope.data);` inside editExpensesDetailCtrl, here $scope.data is the particular item to be edited.And `updateData: function(){ return tempData; }`, inside WebApi factory. You can try modifying the updateData function to something like this - `function(data, index){ angular.extend(tempData[index], data); }` and pass index as well from the controller - `WebApi.updateData($scope.data, $stateParams.expensesId); }`

Comment: thank you for your response, I have actually make it to this jsfddle instead of plunker. http://jsfiddle.net/hin123/tcVhN/129/ I am struggling with the edit button 
    $scope.saveDetail = function (data) {

    } this one sorry for the confusion

Comment: All you do is just created a new function in the service call saveDetailToService and change the input primemter to data and index right? One thing I am not sure is that in the factory, you have the console.log to deplay the changed tempData in the console, Do I need to return tempData as well just like the other return function in the factory?

Comment: No, you dont have to return anything. If you return any non primitive data (object/arrays) from the service/factory to the controller then any change to that object will be reflected in the service as well, since its passed by reference. The method saveDetailToService is just to show you that the data is already updated in the service, you just need to push it in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are data-binding the values of the record that the user is editing, then your `save` function could be as simple as:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    WebApi.updateData($scope.tempData);
};
```

This will only work, of course, if `WebApi.updateData` can detect changes in existing objects.  (In your example, setting `tempData` back to itself preserves the changes on the data-bound object.)

To setup the data-binding on the edit page, you might store the edited object on the scope (`$scope.editedRecord`) and then do something like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="editedRecord.customerName">
```

And so on for each property of the edited record you are exposing.

Comment: Hi Noah, thank you for your reply, so will you do something like this in the controller?     $scope.editedRecord = function (data) {
        $scope.tempData.push(data)

    }

Comment: It will depend on how exactly you are transitioning from your list page to the edit page, but in my snippets above, I assume that `$scope.editedRecord` is one of the objects from `tempData` (like your example object: `{id: 0, owner: "Amy", claimType: "Others", customerName: ABC Company}`).  Your form would data-bind customerName (for instance) so that it would display "ABC Company" and allow the user to change it.  My snippet shows a text box, but you could of course also us a select with predefined options.